# Upload system, similar to youtube

Tags: php, pdf, youtube, upload

I'm trying to create an upload system similar to YouTube.

But in PDF. When you upload a video to YouTube, you create a page.

I already have a code for the page that would be the pdf. But I needed to know how I could create a page that does the upload and modify the html by changing the pdf link

*** pdfListView.loadPdf ("/ upload / ebooks / 1.pdf"); ***

Follow the code below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Demo of pdfListView</title>

    <style>
        .page-container {
          margin: 10px auto;
        }

        .page-view canvas {
          box-shadow: black 0px 0px 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- File from the PDF.JS Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/compatibility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external/pdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">PDFJS.workerSrc = 'external/pdf.worker.js';</script>

    <!-- Leave out the following two files if you don't need a textLayer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/TextLayer.css">
    <script src="src/TextLayerBuilder.js"></script>

    <!-- Leave out the following two files if you don't need an annotations layer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/AnnotationsLayer.css">
    <script src="src/AnnotationsLayerBuilder.js"></script>

    <!-- Core pdfListView file -->
    <script src="src/PdfListView.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main" style="position: absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; left: 0; right: 0; overflow:scroll">
    <!-- The pageContainers go here !-->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.pdfListView = new PDFListView(
        document.getElementById("main"),
        {
            // Comment out the next line to get a listView without textLayer.
            textLayerBuilder: TextLayerBuilder,
            annotationsLayerBuilder: AnnotationsLayerBuilder,
            logLevel: PDFListView.Logger.DEBUG
        }
    );
    pdfListView.loadPdf("http://playofthegame.me/ebooks/A_HIST%c3%93RIA_SECRETA_DA_MA%c3%87ONARIA_E_ORDEM_ROSACRUZ_-_por_Jakim_Booz.pdf");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you facing in your current implementation?

Comment: You loading PDF from "http://playofthegame.me/". Is your HTML code located at "http://playofthegame.me" is well. If not make yourself familiar with CORS policies.